# Find out frequency distribution of a vector and convert it into a matrix/dataframe

Tags: r

I have a vector,

```
Marks : 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 10 10 40 40 40 40 50 50 50 50.
```

I need to find its frequency distribution.
I can get it using the command :

```
    marks<- c(10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,30,30,10,10,40,40,40,40,50,50,50,50)
    marks1<- cbind(table(marks))
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt4mi.png)

Now, when i check the structure of table marks 1, it is only 1 column and not 2.
 So,how would I convert this table into a matix or a datframe and assign attributes so that the output has two columns like this:

```
Marks Freq.
10     5
20     5
30     2
40     4
50     4
```

Is there any way to convert the table's row names into a column itself while converting the table into a matrix/datframe?

Most of the answers I found here are about converting a table ( with predefined column names) to matrix/datframe.

Comment: `marks1 = as.data.frame(table(marks))`

Comment: @GregoryDemin Ah, yes. Thank you. I was trying all types of complex commands.This works just fine.No need to use the `cbind` command as well. I was also able to assign column names using  `colnames(marks1)`.